# choosing between function returns

Tags: c, function, if-statement, return-value

I have written a function which has two different options of what to return:

```
//function to compare the strings in function3
int compare(char* str, char* dest){
  int answer;
  int i;
 int length;
  length = strlen(str);
  // int jlength;
  // jlength = strlen(dest);
  for(i=0; i<length; i++){
    if(str[i] == dest[i]){
      answer = 1;
    }else {
      answer = 2;
    }
  }
  return answer;
}
```

I want to use this function later, and have different things happen depending on what the function has returned. Below are the relevant parts of how I have constructed that:

```
 //compare the reversed str with the orignal, now stored in dest
  compare(str, dest);
  int function3answer;
  if(compare == 1){
    function3answer = 1;
  }else{
   function3answer = 2;
  }
  return function3answer; 
}
```

When I compile I get the error:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
```

Adding single quotes around the 1 does not help (and also isn't really what I want because I am not referencing part of an array) nor does taking it down to one equals sign (this produces a different warning).

Thanks so much!

Comment: 1st mistake: Assign the returned value of your function `compare` into a variable before your if-else statement.

Comment: I do not get it. Are you trying this `if(compare(str, dest) == 1){` ? Or `function3answer = compare(str, dest);` ?

Comment: Also, if you're comparing strings, your `compare` function could be easily substituted by [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) , and it's not correct.

Comment: @woz thank you, your first comment worked! and thank you, but the comparing was part of a larger task so it was easier to write a function I thought. thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @eids just keep in mind my second comment: if you're comparing two strings and using your `compare` function, it's not going to work.

Comment: @woz okay, I'll take a look. you are saying it will not compare correctly?

Comment: @eids consider the case: str1 = abcd and str2 = xyzd. Since you're comparing both strings letter by letter and overwriting the value of the variable `answer` in each iteration, the only iteration that really matters in your case is the last one. In the case I mentioned, `answer` is going to be 1, since the last letter is the same, but str1 != str2.

Comment: @woz the whole point of the compare (which i didn't mention in my original question, i apologize) is to check if the string is a palindrome (same backwards and forwards) so i think i do need to compare letter by letter?

Comment: Well, last time I've done it (and it's been a long time), I solved it by removing the white spaces between the words (in case of phrases) in both strings and comparing the first position of the first string with the last position of the second string, and so on and so forth (also, remember the `\0` terminator). You can still do it your way (reversing the second string and comparing each position), but be careful with spaces, and what I mentioned before. My suggestion is to set `answer` to 2 (I assume you're using 2 as a false value) and return it as soon as you find any differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

> `warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]`

Comes from this line:

```
if(compare == 1){
```

You try to compare a **function** to an **integer**.

To get rid of this error, change the function using `compare`:

```
void some_function(...) {
    //compare the reversed str with the orignal, now stored in dest
    int compare_result = compare(str, dest);

    int function3answer;

    if(compare_result == 1){
        function3answer = 1;
    }else{
        function3answer = 2;
    }
    return function3answer; 
}
```

Now, the `compare` function. The way you implement it won't work as you expect:

- If you compare `"abc"` and `"poc"`, you will have in `for` loop:

  ```
  i = 0, str[0] == 'a', dest[0] == 'p' ==> answer = 2
  i = 1, str[0] == 'b', dest[0] == 'o' ==> answer = 2
  i = 2, str[0] == 'c', dest[0] == 'c' ==> answer = 1
  i = 3, going out for loop and returning **1**.
  ```
- Worst, if you compare `"a long string"` with `"tiny"`, you will get an UB when `i` is `4`.

You could correct the `compare` function this way:

```
#define STRING_IDENTICAL 1
#define STRING_DIFFERENT 2

//function to compare the strings in function3
int compare(char* str, char* dest)
{
    int answer;
    int i;
    int length;
    length = strlen(str);
    int jlength;
    jlength = strlen(dest);

    if (length != jlength)
    {
        /* since size are differents, string are differents */
        return STRING_DIFFERENT;
    }

    for(i=0; i<length; i++){
        if(str[i] != dest[i]){
            /* at least one different character, string are differents */
            return STRING_DIFFERENT;
        }
    }

    /* if we reach this point, that means that string are identical */
    return STRING_IDENTICAL;
}
```

Comment: this explains everything perfectly, thank you so much!